# Showing the right "Running" status in tomcat manager

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm running a servlet in a tomcat container.
All is working correct, tomcat calls the init method of my Servlet and it starts correctly.
When I look at the Tomcat Web Application Manager - List Applications I see the running status is "true".

In the init function I want to check some important settings.
If a check fails, I throw a new ServletException. Now I thought that the running status would change to "false" but it didn't.
So my question is how to stop the servlet from a check in the init function.

Or maybe I just do it the wrong way.

Would like to get some help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Manager does not show the status of individual servlets but of the web application. Individual servlets can fail to start but that doesn't stop the web application from starting.

If you have some checks you want to perform that need to stop the web application starting then put those checks in the contextInitialized method of a ServletContextListener and throw a RuntimeException (or a subclass of it) if the checks fail.

Comment: This solves both issues, the tomcat manager show this servlet as NOT running  and it doesnt continue to load the servlet.
Thanks